# APNS on EC2 not working

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have APNS setup on my dev environment and everything works flawlessly. In production, I can see that devices are being registered and I see the deviceToken in my database and I see that messages are being sent...but users are not receiving them. Is there anything for security groups that have to be done here? I tried reading the below:

[Apple push notification server on Amazon EC2 connected but not receive notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526724/apple-push-notification-server-on-amazon-ec2-connected-but-not-receive-notificat)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

I tried to telnet to gateway.push.apple.com and i was able to... Is there anything else that I am missing??

**EDIT**

My server logs are fine, and after tons of debugging seems like the issue has to be with APNS. Can somebody please tell me if my setup is ok?

I'm using the dev provisioning profile and im testing in a prod-like environment (but still not prod) with the prod apns certificate and key. Is this not allowed? Am I not allowed to use the dev provisioning profile to test it myself this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificates should match up. You can't use the production APNS cert/key to send to development provisioning profiles, and vice versa.

From the documentation on [push notification provisioning](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1):

> Each certificate is also limited to one of two development environments, each with its own assigned IP address.
>
> You must get separate certificates for the sandbox (development) environment and the production environment.

Comment: Yeah...realized this much later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208669/enabling-apple-push-notifications-for-ad-hoc-distribution-environment